# How to redirect to register page after login attempt?

Tags: symfony, redirect, fosuserbundle

I want to redirect a user that is not registered yet to the registration page. So if a user enters an email/username that is not registered, I want to redirect to the /register path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function get() on null for FOSuserBundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539822/call-to-a-member-function-get-on-null-for-fosuserbundle)

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the user to fos' registration form like this (from within a controller):

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_registration_register');
```