# Call to a member function get() on null for FOSuserBundle

Tags: symfony, authentication, interface

I am trying to do a redirect to the registration page, if a username does not exists in the user tables. I have done all the configurations needed and I have created the handler that looks like:

```
namespace UserBundle\Redirection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;

class AfterLoginFailureRedirection implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * AfterLoginFailureRedirection constructor.
     * @param RouterInterface $router
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AuthenticationException $token
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        //$request = $this->container->get('request');
        $token=$exception->getToken();
        $username=$token->getUsername();
        //$username = $request->request->get('email');
        $user = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByUsername($username);

        if(!$user->isUser()) {
            $url=$this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_register');
            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }
    }
}
```

For this part of the code I am getting the error:

```
$user = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByUsername($username);
```

Why is this happening?

Edit:
I initialized correcly constructor.
I inserted the code: else { $url=$this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_sec‌​urity_login'); return new RedirectResponse($url); } but it just redirects me without the login errors

Comment: You are missing to add `$this->container = $container` in your `__constructor` method.

Comment: now it works, but if the user exists and the password is incorrect it shows: Authentication Failure Handler did not return a Response

Comment: I inserted the code: else
        {
            $url=$this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_security_login');
            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        } but it just redirects me without the login errors.

Comment: @yceruto Please help me.

Comment: What do you want to do ? It's not a good practice. When auth fail you should stay on the same page.

Comment: Update your question with the latest code because it's difficult to tell what is what.  In general, stick to one question at a time.  @yceruto answered your first question.  Then you changed it in the comments section.  Can you see how that might make things difficult?  Might even go so far as to close this one and open a new one.

Comment: I created a new question @Cerad. Can you have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551524/authentication-failure-handler-did-not-return-a-response